# Generating PDF out of HTML template using flying_ruby_saucer gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, flying-saucer

My requirement is I am generating PDF out of the pre-rendered HTML template. This template is a multi-lingual page and uses custom fonts from our clients.

Following approaches tried:

- I used `wicked_pdf` (internally uses `wkhtmltopdf-binary`) gem to achieve this, but the issues I face are: font kerning arent proper as every other character get overlapped on other. The same font appears proper on actual PDF. I included all CSSes directly into the HEAD -> STYLE, tried various tricks by setting letter-spacing, etc. but nothing worked.
- So, now using `flying_ruby_saucer`. Font kerning looks proper. But neither characters from Arabic OR HINDI is printed on PDF nor custom font is picked up.
  I have declared custom font as:

  ```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('http://localhost:3000/assets/MyFont.ttf');
  }
  body{ font-family:"My Font"; }
  ```

But this doesnot work either as PDF generated shows default font family. Non-ascii characters arent printed too.

Could anyone please help me fixing this (include foreign characters as well as include custom fonts)?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried wicked_pdf gem?

Comment: Yes, I have tried wicked_pdf, This isnt giving me the results I needed. Also I highlighted libraries in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a problem with UTF-8 based fonts, you could use [prawn gem](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) because this gem actually supports UTF-8 encoding also l18n is supported.

Comment: prawn isnt a html to pdf generator. And it doesnot supports all CSSes as well